# ¿Como hacer que un select sea requerido si se cumple una condición?

Tags: validación, laravel-7

Tengo un select tipo de unidad con 3 opciones y otro select sección que debe ser requerido solo si en tipo de unidad se ha seleccionado video o zip.

```
            return [
                'title' => 'required|min:6|max:200',
                'content' => 'required|min:10',
                'course_id' => [
                    'required',
                    Rule::exists('courses', 'id')
                ],
                'unit_type' => [
                    'required',
                    Rule::in(Unit::unitTypes())
                ],
                'section' => 'required_if:unit_type,'.Unit::ZIP.'|required_if:unit_type,'.Unit::VIDEO,
                'file' => 'required_if:unit_type,'.Unit::ZIP.'|file',
                'video' => 'required_if:unit_type,'.Unit::VIDEO,
                'unit_time' => 'required_if:unit_type,'.Unit::VIDEO,
            ];
```

He probado required_if de este modo y no funciona. También he probado:

```
 'section' => 'required_if:unit_type,'.Unit::ZIP.','.Unit::VIDEO,
```

y también he probado:

```
    'section' => [
                    'required_if:unit_type,'.Unit::ZIP.','.Unit::VIDEO
                ],
```

Alguna idea por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví, tenía un value "0" en el option que sirve de placeholder y debía estar vacío para que funcionara el required_if, entonces en la norma de validación puse:

```
  'section' => [
         'required_if:unit_type,'.Unit::VIDEO.','.Unit::ZIP,
   ],
```